# Gridview scrolling - recycleview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm trying to recycle the gridview items, as the current solution works but is laggy and eats up resources. However, i can't figure out how to. The android developer site's example didn't work for me.

my getview() method:

```
public View getView(int position, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
    long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

View localView = MMWeb.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
TextView localTextView = (TextView)localView.findViewById(2131034115);
ImageView localImageView = (ImageView)localView.findViewById(2131034114);

cItem = items.get(position);
cItem.add(Integer.toString(position));
localTextView.setText(getItemName());
Bitmap localBitmap = d.getImage(cItem.get(3), cItem.get(2));
localImageView.setImageBitmap(localBitmap);
Common.toLog("getView took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) + " ms");
return localView; }
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?? any suggestions on how to solve this will be appreciated!

Comment: Worth watching the [Google IO video on UI performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA)

Comment: @Merlin Im watching that right now... but cant get the viewholder to work (if i put the viewholder class right after getView() i get an "Syntax error on token 'Class', invalid type" error --edit: nooby error: i wrote "ViewHolder()" instead of "ViewHolder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `paramView`, which is the reusable view passed by your adapterview as it is no longer visible on the screen.

```
 if (paramView == null) {
    // inflate a new view into paramView.
    paramView = MMWeb.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
 }
 // fill the paramView
 TextView localTextView = (TextView)paramView .findViewById(2131034115);
 ImageView localImageView = (ImageView)paramView .findViewById(2131034114);

 cItem = items.get(position);
 cItem.add(Integer.toString(position));
 localTextView.setText(getItemName());
 Bitmap localBitmap = d.getImage(cItem.get(3), cItem.get(2));
 localImageView.setImageBitmap(localBitmap);

 return  paramView;
```

Comment: That does the trick... however this reintroduces another problem (the reason why i removed the recycling in the first place when i first started to use the gridview)

The items jump are reordered randomly as i scroll. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: after assigning the items outside the if-statement the problem was solved.